# Calculate coefficients in multiple regression

Tags: r, multiple-regression, lm

I have a model where tree height is a function of diameter and species type. 
`(Tree height)^n= a0+ a1*Diameter+ a2*Type`
I would like to calculate the coefficients a0, a1,a2 and n. a0,a1,a2 can be easily calculated from the lm function in R. I am wondering how can i calculate n. Do i need to provide arbitrary values to n, and compare with the coefficient of determination.

Comment: If $n$ is forced to be an integer, it's probably a low one, so I would just fit every possible model with $n=1,2,3...$ and compare the quality of each model. If you fit two or three consecutive models with no improvement, then it's probably time to stop your search

Comment: Check out the `nls` function.  You can define the function and the solver will fit the coefficients.

Comment: 1. You can't normally compare $R^2$ values across differently transformed responses.

2. You can nevertheless fit a nonlinear model like this in a variety of ways (nls, generalized linear models, etc). However, since you've only specified half of the model (you said nothing about the behavior of the variability about the model), we have no basis on which to choose between alternatives. Note that an assumption appropriate for one power (n) will imply a different assumption at another value of n (most noticeably - but not only - in relation to the variance of the conditional distribution).

Comment: e.g. it's completely inconsistent to assume that the conditional variance of height$^{0.5}$ and height$^{1.5}$ are both constant (if one were, the other would not be)... similarly, they won't both be equally skew or heavy-tailed. A number of answers on site discuss each of those issues.